# NoIP, multiple domains, one dynamic IP, 2 servers using same port

Tags: dns, noip

I can't seem to wrap my head around something to know if it is or not possible.

Situation:

- I have noip that redirect to my dynamic IP
- I have two local servers running services, including web server, one on each server, both listening on port 80
  I have multiple domains names on no IP.

What I would like:

- access port 80 from domain 1 that redirect on my dynamic IP and hit server 1 web server
- access port 80 from domain 2 that redirect on my dynamic IP and hit server 2 web server

Things I don't know:

- will I be able to detect it's coming from domain 1 or 2? if that is the case, then I guess I could use a reverse proxy that my router would point to when request arrive on port 80 then dispatch to server 1 or 2?

What I get to avoid is to change port to redirect to the good server(ex: 80, 81).

Thank you, any help or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to use a reverse proxy to inspect the domain name and then use the name to choose which backend handles the request.  NoIP can't do it from its end because it has to send the traffic to only one IP and port.  Your router probably doesn't have functionality to do hostname based http request routing, and unless it's an especially high quality router, you probably wouldn't want it to take part in that anyway.

Comment: Actually, I am wondering if this is possible: domain 1 port 80 > dynamic IP port 80 > forward to nginx server as reverse proxy > nginx check domain and redirect to correct local IP. The part I'm not sure is if nginx will understand from which domain it's coming from.

Comment: yep, that's the idea.  Nginx supports "virtual hosting", in which the domain name is used to distinguish requests to different hosts.  You can even run it on the application servers as there's not much to it resource-wise